# Primary key index is not being used

Tags: oracle, primary-key, oracle12c, query-performance

I'm using Oracle 12C and I have the following code

```
SELECT
        d.id,
        'Status' "ImportStatus",
        p.importid "ImportID",
        macid,
        p.daterequire "CreateDate",
        p.dateimport "DateImPort",
        TRANSLATE(p.accrequire USING NCHAR_CS) "CreateBy",
        TRANSLATE(p.accimport USING NCHAR_CS) "AccImPort",
        0 "isEdit",
        employee,
        deptid partner,
        equipmentid
    FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                id,
                importid,
                daterequire,
                dateimport,
                accrequire,
                accimport,
                subdeptid employee,
                deptid
            FROM
                tableA
            WHERE
                estatus = 2
                AND createdate BETWEEN to_timestamp('01/01/2019','dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_timestamp('12/02/2019','dd/mm/yyyy')
        ) p
        INNER JOIN tableB d ON d.importid = p.id
```

The TableA had 5m values and TableB had 3m values.

Importid is an unique column with varchar2 datatype. ID is PK with number datatype.

Here is the execution plan:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR2Q9.png
```

As can be seen, there is no index in PK and It lead to high cost. Is there any way to help me resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider that **indexes are not always a good idea**.

If Oracle has to read *most* data from a table, it will use a FULL TABLE SCAN, since it's faster than reading blocks of index first and then reading blocks of data second. Too much of IO operations involved.

Now, back to your question. 
You can force Oracle to use an index, if you want to, by providing a hint:

```
/*+ INDEX(table_name index_name) */
```

You can add it to your query and check what happens to the query plan and how much the new plan will cost:

```
SELECT  /*+ INDEX(tableA index_name) */     --replace 'index_name' with the name of your index
        d.id,
        'Status' "ImportStatus",
        p.importid "ImportID",
        macid,
        p.daterequire "CreateDate",
        p.dateimport "DateImPort",
        TRANSLATE(p.accrequire USING NCHAR_CS) "CreateBy",
        TRANSLATE(p.accimport USING NCHAR_CS) "AccImPort",
        0 "isEdit",
        employee,
        deptid partner,
        equipmentid
    FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                id,
                importid,
                daterequire,
                dateimport,
                accrequire,
                accimport,
                subdeptid employee,
                deptid
            FROM
                tableA
            WHERE
                estatus = 2
                AND createdate BETWEEN to_timestamp('01/01/2019','dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_timestamp('12/02/2019','dd/mm/yyyy')
        ) p
        INNER JOIN tableB d ON d.importid = p.id
```

Comment: I tried use hint to force but useless. It made cost and elapsed time higher than not force

Comment: That only means, that Oracle selects a better execution plan to perform your query, which does not innvole using the index (as I said before, indexes are not always a good idea). To speed up performance, you could try partitioning your TableA by `createdate` (and probably `estatus`) column and see if that helps.